# request.raw_post is returning nil when sending in a webhook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, webhooks

The application I'm working on is currently taking in webhooks from GitHub. We're trying to do something like the following:

```
raw_payload = request.raw_post
original_payload = JSON.parse(raw_payload)
```

And then `original_payload` would be the parsed raw data from the webhook. Everything works locally when I use a `curl` command to send the webhook: the raw data is found, and the JSON is parsed. However, whenever I put it up on my staging environment and  it starts getting *real* webhooks from GitHub, it starts to break with this error:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of nil into String):
json (1.8.3) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `initialize'
json (1.8.3) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `new'
json (1.8.3) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
```

on the line that states `JSON.parse(raw_payload)`, basically meaning that `raw_payload` is nil. What scenario would have `request.raw_post` return nil on staging, but work correctly in development?

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 2):

Figured out my own question. The issue was happening with the whole `request.raw_post` thing. Although the true reason to why `raw_post` was returning `nil` unfortunately remains sort of a mystery (we assume it has something to do with the webhook data being deleted and refreshed before we can grab it), we did find a workaround:

```
raw_parameters = request.request_parameters
```

And then we can grab values from `raw_parameters` like so:

```
new_request[:github_action] = raw_parameters["action"]
```

Moreover, this way, if there is no `raw_parameters["action"]`, then nothing will change with `new_request`. This solved all of our issues!

Sorry I couldn't find the exact reason `raw_post` was returning `nil`!